# Como usar um rota para servir uma pasta inteira de arquivos?

Tags: javascript, express.js

Quero que a rota `app.get("/")` mostre a pasta statica configurada no caminho abaixo:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client")))
```

como arrumar meu código para isto?

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client")))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("new player")
    res.send("hi")
})
```

Comment: Rafael, você sabe para que serve e com funciona o `app.use()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o express servir arquivos estáticos e renderizar um site por exemplo ou mostrar suas pastas e arquivos, Usando a lib `serve-index` ele mostrará o conteúdo da sua pasta public igual o da imagem.Através deste código:

```
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
app.use('/public', serveIndex(__dirname + '/public'));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

caso queira fazer isso na rota `/` basta trocar `/public` para `/`

```
app.use('/', serveIndex(__dirname + '/public'));
```

mas se você quiser renderizar os arquivos estáticos como um `html, css e js` na rota get, basta usar esse código:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]